# Trackpad issue with 2010 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

While I was using my MacBook Pro, I went to setting and ironically I disabled all the finger touch option from Trackpad. Now I can't click anything just the icon is moving around. I tried to plug in another keyboard and mouse in the USB drive was showing press to continue. Sadly I can't click at all.

Anyone with the idea how to restore the option as I am having lots of difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

First try to restart the computer.

If the keyboard still responds try to get to terminal from quick search. (cmd space normally)

in terminal you can try to change the preferences via the command "defaults"
the folling command outputs the various settings.

```
defaults read com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad
```

The output for me is here. 1 means active (or true), 0 means not ative (or false).

```
{
    Clicking = 1;
    DragLock = 0;
    Dragging = 0;
    TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick = 0;
    TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadHandResting = 1;
    TrackpadHorizScroll = 1;
    TrackpadMomentumScroll = 1;
    TrackpadPinch = 1;
    TrackpadRightClick = 1;
    TrackpadRotate = 1;
    TrackpadScroll = 1;
    TrackpadThreeFingerDrag = 0;
    TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture = 0;
    TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture = 0;
    TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture = 1;
    TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture = 3;
    USBMouseStopsTrackpad = 0;
    UserPreferences = 1;
    version = 5;
}
```

to set any of these keys type

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad KeyFromAboveList -bool true
```

Comment: Wow, I think I love Terminal commands!

Answer (score 0):

I did restarted the system keyboard does work normally and as per your above instruction went to terminal search went to 
defaults read com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad and its showing TrackpadRightClick = 0;

and i tried making as adjustment as per above instruction 
which is defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad KeyFromAboveList -bool true
the reply i got is 
defaults have not been changed'
-bash: -boo1: command not found
Can you elaborate ???